# Installing gtk3 + glade on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I am new to python and I have been trying to install gtk3 to use with glade to build a GUI with Python 2.7. I have successfully installed Glade, however I am having some major issues finding and running gtk3 for windows. I have visited the [gtk website](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php) and have followed their instructions with the MSYS2 installer, but when I try to conda install with the anaconda prompt or import gtk, I get errors saying that there is no module named gtk. I have also downloaded the win64 zip of gtk3 from [tarnyko](http://www.tarnyko.net/dl/gtk.htm) and have tried to put the unzipped file into Lib>site-packages ad then try to conda install and import, but still no luck. I'm running on a 64 bit Windows 10 OS.

Does anyone knows how to properly get everything installed and running?

Comment: taryko runtime and devel zips are outdated. You should use pacman package installer inside msys2. To deploy GTK+ 3 applications it's a bit harder. You must bundle a bunch of files on specific locations together with msys2.dll but first you should set up your development environment.

Comment: @JoséFonte AFAIK, msys2.dll is normally not required unless you explicitly link to the features it provides.

Answer (score 4):

Please avoid the tarnyko releases, as they are out-of-date and unmaintained now (3.6 while the last GTK+ version as I'm writing this is 3.22). The preferred way to install GTK on Windows is through MSYS2, as stated on the [GTK+ download page for Windows](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php). I rewrote that page a few weeks ago, and I'll do my best to fix things there if needed.

Now please explain this:

> when I try to conda install with the anaconda prompt or import gtk, I
>   get errors saying that there is no module named gtk

What do you mean by `conda install`? You should only use the `pacman` package manager provided by MSYS2 to setup your environment. Did you follow all the instructions on http://www.msys2.org ? Did you install using `pacman` the gtk3 library? Did you install the python bindings as stated in ***Step 4 (optional): Install the Python bindings*** ?

I got a running system by just exactly following step by step the instructions I have put on the GTK website. So please make sure you read and follow every step, and copy-paste error messages here when they happen.